# How to assign a specific value according to condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with numbers (some of them are infinite).

What I must do is the following:
All numbers greater than 15 or under -15 must be assigned the value 1, otherwise (between -15 and 15) it is assigned the value 0.

I have tried with:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].mask((df['B'] > 15, 1) | (df['B'] < -15, 1))
df['B'] = df['B'].where(df['B'] == 1, 0)
```

But got:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with the `.between()` method:

```
>>> df           # example DF
    B
0   1
1   9
2 -27
3  15
4  45
5  -6
>>> df["B"][df["B"].between(-15, 15)] = 0
>>> df["B"][~df["B"].between(-15, 15)] = 1
>>> df
   B
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0
```

Comment: Can simplify to `(~df["B"].between(-15, 15)).astype(int)`.

Comment: @ddejohn: Sure, fair enough. But that can only set the elements to `0` or `1`. I try to give generic enough answers because questions often don't say what's *really* needed, and it turns out `0` and `1` were just examples.

Comment: That's fair, although I think it's safe to assume here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.apply()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [-20, -12, 8, 11, 24]})
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x > 15 or x < -15 else 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I felt bad spamming sj95126, so I'll just provide some extra solutions here.

If you *actually* need `0`s and `1`s:

```py
(~df["B"].between(-15, 15)).astype(int)
```

If you're already using `numpy`, but need more generic replacement (not `0`s and `1`s):

```py
np.where(df["B"].between(-15, 15), val_if_between, val_if_not_between)
```

If you're not using `numpy` but still need more generic replacement:

```py
df["B"].between(-15, 15).replace({True: val_if_between, False: val_if_not_between})
```

Comment: No worries, but thanks. It's always best if solutions don't get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To closely follow your thinking process:

```
df.loc[
    (df['B'] > 15) | (df['B'] < -15),
    'B',
] = 1
```

`df.loc[...]` is a mandatory syntax to master for pandas